# Setting opacity of a rectangle

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an event fired when some button is being clicked

```
private void set_Opacity(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Opacity = 0;
    }
```

But there's no effect when the button is clicked. What am I doing wrong? 
Thanks.

**EDIT :**
I'll give some background about what I am trying to do:

I have created a customized button that should minimize my window with a fade out animation so here's the code of it:

```
 private void minimize_Window(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var anim = new DoubleAnimation(0, (Duration)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        anim.Completed += (s, _) => this.Minimize();
        this.BeginAnimation(UIElement.OpacityProperty, anim);



    }
    private void Minimize()
    {
        WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
    }
```

It works perfectly fine, though the problem is that when I try to retrieve my program from the task bar it won't do anything (I am not able to see the program when I click on it from the taskbar after it minimized). What I understand from it is that the opacity of my program is being set to 0 while it got minimized(because of the animation). 
So I used the Activated event calling that method:

```
private void set_Opacity(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rectangle2.Opacity = 1;
        WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
    }
```

And still, same issue. Hope you could help.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What is 'this' in the context of your event handler? I.E. where is this event handler defined and upon which element is the opacity being set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem seems to be that in most cases, `this` is going to be a `Window`. My assumption though, is that you are not trying to set the entire window to invisible, rather a Rectangle. You need to give your Rectangle a name using `x:Name` attribute. Here is an example:

```xml
<Rectangle Width="40" Height="40" x:Name="MyRectangle" Fill="Red" />
```

Then, in your button click:

```
private void set_Opacity(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyRectangle.Opacity = 0;
}
```

If you really are trying to set the entire `Window`'s transparency:

An entire Window can't have it's opacity set unless you specify `AllowTransparency` to true and `WindowStyle` to None in your XAML:

```xml
<Window x:Class="ScratchApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        AllowsTransparency="true" WindowStyle="None">
```

Note the attributes being set.

**EDIT**:

> I need an event to be fired when my program is being activated back from my task bar. Do you have any idea what event I could use?

Use the `Window.Activated` event. From your XAML:

```xml
<Window Activated="Window_Activated">
```

And in your C#:

```
private void Window_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Put code here
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, I just had to change "this" to "rectangle2".. I was setting the opacity of the button instead of the rectangle ><. Though I am facing another problem, maybe you could help? I need an event to be fired when my program is being activated back from my task bar. Do you have any idea what event I could use?

Comment: Please see my edited post ^ hope you can help if you are able to:)

Answer (score 0):

This should have some effect (assuming this is being called on a WPF applications main window it will make the whole window go black).

It almost sounds like the event handler isn't correctly wired up. Try setting a break point on the opacity setting line or right clicking on the set_opacity function name and selection 'Find All References', you should see an event handler being created in the windowname.g.cs file.

Comment: I just chekced it now, the event is getting called.